# Youtube player custom app force closes every time

Tags: java, android, youtube-api

I'm now trying something with a youtube custom player. I'm trying to have it play a video containing a playlist of a certain game's original soundtracks.

The thing is, everything was done by the book (again), yet I still have this concurring problem of force stopping every time I tried to open the APK. Here are the code :

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <view
        android:id="@+id/YoutubePlayView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Play Video" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java :

```
package my.videoplayerapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    YouTubePlayerView mYoutubePlayerView;
    Button PlayVidButton;
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener mOnInitializedListener;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Starting.");
        PlayVidButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        mYoutubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.YoutubePlayView);

        mOnInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Initialization Done.");

                youTubePlayer.loadVideo("DBToMwdYBME");
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Initialization Failed.");
            }
        };

        PlayVidButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Initializing Youtube Player.");
                mYoutubePlayerView.initialize((YoutubeVidPlayerConfig.getApiKey()), mOnInitializedListener);
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Initialization Done.");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Logcat, linked : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w5TfCIfyCWCrOZmrjb0lzTpndoQc2SJ0

I'm trying to actually be able to play the video through the button, I know the method of playing the next video or even playing sequence of videos, I just don't know why it keeps on crashing as I speak right now...

Any help would be appreciated in advance!

Comment: Your `<view>` element isn't correct. Either change it to a `<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>` tag, or add `class="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView"` to the `<view>` tag you have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a view with the id of "YoutubePlayView" but your class is called "YoutubePlayerView". Change one of them and it should work (well it shouldn't force close at this spot).

Comment: Sadly that didn't solve the problem. I've changed the ID of the view to "YoutubePlayerView" but it still crashes and force closes.

Comment: Oh. Didn't realize your class name was YouTubePlayerView. it's case sensitive. Change the view to that (capital t instead of lowercase)